# Foundation Accordion Expand/Collapse All Button

Tags: jquery, accordion, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Foundation 3 Accordion
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/elements.php

I want to add a button above the accordion that expands or collapses all of them.

What javascript do I need to add to the button to make it work?

Here is the link:
http://mheg.turnpostinteractive.com/about-mheg-2/staff/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is a little lacking but to open them all at once it would be like this:

```
$("#yourButton").click( function() {
    $(".accordion li").removeClass("active").addClass("active");
});
```

The reason you are removing the class first is in case you already have one open, you don't add a second "active" class to it. That should be it. Obviously "#yourButton would be replaced by the selector for the button you add to expand all of them.

To close them all you you use this:

```
$("accordion li").removeClass("active");
```

Depending on how you want the button to behave you can use toggles (see jQuery documentation) or write your own logic depending on the current state of each item. You can check to see if each accordion is open or closed by:

```
$(".accordion li:nth-child(n)").hasClass("active");
```

n would be the accordion tab you are checking.

Comment: I can't get the toggle to work yet. Can you help with that, too?

Comment: You need to describe what you are trying to do if you wanted help, but you are better off with One "Open All" and a 2nd "Close All" button since it is ambiguous as a single button. For example - should it open all if there is already a tab open? If two tabs are open and you click the button should it open the last tab or should it close the first two? Having open/close both on a single button is asking for trouble. Not only is it confusing logic, but it will confuse users.

Comment: PS: If my expand and collapse works great and I answered your question, make sure you accept the answer!

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I will use two separate links.

Comment: Could you please look at the page. http://mheg.turnpostinteractive.com/about-mheg-2/staff/ the buttons work great until the other accordions are clicked, and then they don't work properly. Thank you.

Comment: Here is where the javascript is at: http://mheg.turnpostinteractive.com/wp-content/themes/mheg_theme/js/app.js?ver=3.5

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service or code review service...You need to go through the site yourself and explain what is happening/what isn't happening. For example, if after the accordions are closed, when you click on them again the "active" class isn't showing up. You need to use firebug or something similar to explain what is going on. After you find the problem, you should isolate that from the REST of your site using jsfiddle. The problem may not be related to the question above and may be something else on your site causing the problem - without jsfiddle I can't know.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I ended up going another route.

http://anasnakawa.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/jquery-ui-multi-open-accordion/

http://jsfiddle.net/anasnakawa/du9EM/2/